# Why this model doesn't fit the result

Tags: python, tensorflow

Im trying to execute the code below, but what happend is that this machine doesn't fit the value when I test this specific number 474244.073

```
import tensorFlow as tf
import numPy as np

from tensorFlow import Keras

model=tf.keras.Sequential([keras.layers.Dense(units =1, input_shape=[1])])

model.compile(loss='mean_squared_error',
          optimizer=tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(0.1))

a= float(input("enter the wanted value to convert : "))

xs=np.array([443707.401,455897.072,
396833.899,407426.699,435646.069,
419953.188,436349.443,633372.629,
572704.102,506379.29,596808.359,
622705.893,521749.843,500965.861,
558482.399,672648.564,739873.87,
459092.199,485007.612,579586.959,
509713.739,725009.687,727394.13,
658740.26,485686.823,461640.1,502495.219,
625584.252,680222.202,760907.585,
738381.47,712415.6], dtype=float)


ys=np.array([443417.925,455608.023,397588.538,407135.987,435356.29,419662.8`42,436059.613,633089.564,
572418.983,506091.937,596524.026,
622422.445,521463.004,500678.296,
558196.649,672366.797,739594.302,
458803.188,484719.43,579302.029,
509426.339,724729.561,727114.01,
658457.788,485398.691,461351.171,
502207.616,625300.699,679940.373,
760628.252,738101.41,712134.732],dtype=float)

model.fit(xs,ys,epochs=100)

result= (model.predict([a]))

print(result)
```

My expected output should be like this : `(473955.629)`

While when i execute this code its working good :

```
import tensorflow as tf

import numpy as np

from tensorflow import keras

model=tf.keras.Sequential([keras.layers.Dense(units =1, input_shape=[1])])

model.compile(optimizer='sgd',loss='mean_squared_error')

a= float(input("enter the wanted value to convert : "))

xs=np.array([2,3,4], dtype=float)

ys=np.array([100,200,300],dtype=float)

model.fit(xs,ys,epochs=4000)

result= (model.predict([a]))

print(result)
```

Any ideas or solutions ?
Many thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Check the shape of xs and ys in your code. I think your xs has 27 values while ys has only 24 values.
The shapes of both the arrays must be same to fit the model correctly.

Comment: I've checked the data and it's 32 for each x and y